# multer removes the body object from the incoming request

Tags: node.js, api, express, multer, busboy

When I use multer to parse a multipart data, the `req.body` is null

by inspecting the source code, I found out that it sets req.body to null

[image]

Do I miss something here?

Answer (score 0):

by deeply understand the encoding `multipart/form-data`, I found out that the data itself is placed inside the headers, middlewares like multer just populate the data into req.body and req.files